# I am not getting the data expected from the api call instead I get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have this file I call PostAPi.js where I have all my functions and then in my Posts.js where I make the call.

`api.getPosts()` and `data` in the Posts.js, returns undefined instead of the data.

PostsApi.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({  
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});

export const getPosts = () => {
  api.get("/posts").then((response) => response.data); // console.log(response.data) returns the data which is an array of objects but I keep getting undefined in the Posts.js file.
};
```

Posts.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import * as api from "./PostApi"

const Users = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("posts");
    console.log(api.getPosts()) // returns undefined as well
  }, [])

  const { data } = useQuery("posts", api.getPosts)
  console.log(data) // returns undefined
```

package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.0.10",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.0.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^4.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

Comment: can u share ur package.json?

Comment: Where did you share it?

Comment: check the updated question.

Comment: I posted an answer check that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your **PostsApi.js** return the **promise**

```
export const getPosts = () => {
          return api.get("/posts").then((response) => response.data); // console.log(response.data) returns the data which is an array of objects but I keep getting undefined in the Posts.js file.
        };
```

And In your **Posts.js** file **consume** that **promise**

```
useEffect(() => {
        api.getPosts().then((res) => {
          console.log("In APP res", res);
        });
      }, []);
```

Comment: I get this error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"

Comment: I have updated my answer please try this solution.

Comment: Thank you, it now returns the data but for the data from the useQuery, it still returns undefined.

Comment: You have to consume the promise for  useQuery as well try this code.                      
  const {  data  } = useQuery("posts", async () => {
    const res = await api.getPosts();
    return res.json();
  });

Answer (score 1):

```js
// update your PostApi.js like the following
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
});

export const getPosts = async () => {
  try {
    const response = (await api.get("/posts")).data;
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    return err.message;
  }
};
```

```js
// update the following line 
const { data } = useQuery(["posts"], api.getPosts())
```

Comment: I still get the data to be undefined.